# Find license details in DevOps Server 2019

Tags: azure-devops-server-2019

We upgraded our TFS to DevOpsServer 2019 U1.1
Where do I find now how many user cal's I have installed and to what user there are assigned to in DevOps2019 ?

Comment: Assigned users can be found under access levels..http://yourtfsserver:8080/tfs/_admin/_licenses
However I am not sure if TFS provides an interface on how many Cal licenses you have purchased.

Answer (score 1):

> Where do I find now how many user cal's I have installed and to what user there are assigned to in DevOps2019 ?

According to the document [Understand TFS Licensing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/govdev/understand-tfs-licensing):

> The two ways to acquire TFS CALs are:
>
> 1. Purchase a TFS User CAL   (sku: 126-00196)
> 2. 1 TFS CAL (and 1 TFS Server license) is included in each Visual
>    Studio/MSDN subscription. Thus, anyone who has an active MSDN
>    subscription assigned to them is covered with a TFS CAL.

Thus, anyone who has an active MSDN subscription assigned to them is covered with a Azure Devops server CAL.

But if you purchased tfs cals separately, it seems TFS not provides an interface on how many Cal licenses you have purchased.

To get the user there are assigned to in DevOps2019 , you could go to the Access levels:

[image]

Hope this helps.